# Problema com offset e limit MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Quando realizo uma consulta usando limit e offset o banco de dados retorna uma linha a menos do que deveria. Qual é o problema? Cache? Lock? Índice? Dados?

Por exemplo:

```
select distinct(id_table1) from table_1
join table_2 on table_2.id_table2 = table1.id_table2
where table2.campo = numero_qualquer
limit 100
offset 523800;
```

A query acima retorna 99 resultados invés de 100.

Se eu fizer a mesma query com limit 1 e offset 523842 retorna 0 resultados. Note que se eu aumentar o limite para 2 retorna 1. Não sei porque essa linha não é exibida ela aparentemente é contada pelo offset para pular mas não é exibida no resultado do limit.

As tabelas são em MyISAM, já reparei índice e dados e nada de funcionar.

Comment: vc está usando alguma ide? workbench? se executar em linha de comando o que acontece?

Comment: acontece a mesma coisa

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que quando você faz um `LIMIT` com `GROUP_BY` ou `DISTINCT` o `OFFSET` passa a mudar de acordo com o agrupamento criado. 
então o `id 523800` não faz referencia a posição dele na `TABELA` e sim a posição dele no agrupamento, sendo assim quando o agrupamento foi criado, talvez  você não possua mais 100 registros à partir desse índice e sim apenas 99.

Tente aumentar o número do `LIMIT` para 200, ele continuará a ser 99.

Comment: conforme informei se o offset for de 523842 e o limit de 1 o banco retorna 0 registros se o limite for 2 retorna 1, portanto é nesse ponto que está o problema, se eu fizer um limit de 200 ele retorna 199 registros, a partir desse ponto em diante sempre é retornado um a menos, o select em questão tem mais de 3 milhões de resultados

Comment: Bom o que consegui analisar ontem foi isso, que coloquei como resposta, até fiz uma simulação com bastante dados aqui, porém realmente fica difícil sem os dados reais. =/